# typeOf is not defined

Tags: javascript, browser

I normally use typeOf() function instead of typeof operator to check the data type, however, I came across two problems today:

1. typeOf() and typeof are giving me a different result.

[image]

2. even worse, after I updated my Chrome browser, I am getting 'typeOf is not defined' message.

[image]
So my question is:

1. What is the difference between typeOf() and typeof?
2. Why am i getting 'typeOf is not defined' after updating Chrome? Is typeOf() obsolete?

Comment: "*What is the difference between typeOf() and typeof?*" the one with the capital letter does not exist by default

Comment: Also `typeof 1 + "2"` will be resolves as `(typeof 1) + "2"` due to precedence rules

Answer (score 6):

There is no `typeOf` function, there exist only `typeof` operator - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof

`typeof 1 + "2"` is getting evaluated as ->

```
(typeof 1) + "2"

"number" + "2"

"number2" <-- Concatenation
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no typeOf function, only the [type of operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof). As you can see, your code in vanilla javascript is throwing errors to the console:

```js
typeOf("1");
typeOf(false);
```

Also, `1 + "1"` will be concat was a string (`"11"`). So, by doing `typeof (1+"1")` you are doing `typeof("11")` which is indeed a string.

Ultimately, you could implement your own function like this, to achieve the result that you want:

```js
let typeOf = (type) => console.log(typeof (type)); 
typeOf(1 + "1");
```

Comment: @randomSoul, The picture I posted is a snapshot of my screen, so there is actually 'typeOf', at least until I update my Chrome browser.

Comment: @Mike can you please tell us the chrome version that the typeof function works? Before tou have update it

Comment: Unfortunately, I haven't noticed the version before updating but it is not that old because I bought my laptop just around four months ago.